# Best Practice for fill ViewModel with different Repositories

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I'm trying to find out the best way to doing this code 
(because I think, my way locks not good):
I've tried to make it as easy to understand the problem.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
var user=new User();
user.load(1);
return View(user);
}

load(int id )
{
//pseudocode:
//1. load user from repository1     
//2. load address from repository2
//3.load payments from repository3
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with the way you are doing it now?

Comment: The ViewModel includes DB-Code/Logic-Code. Normally, the ViewModel should not include Logic code. I often read this.

Comment: that was the answer I was looking for. In that case just refactor the code into it's own class. I usually name such classes as model services. so in your case it would be `UserModelService`. And inject `UserModelService` as a dependency into your controller

Comment: Can you please explain  with a code snippet?

Comment: I have added an answer containing the code snippet. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

We would first create a `UserModelService` as below

```
public class UserModelService
{
    public User Load(int id)
    {
        var userRepository = new UserRepository();
        var user = userRepository.Load(id);

        var addressRepository = new AddressRepository();
        user.Address = addressRepository.LoadForUserId(id);
        return user;
    }
}
```

We would then modify the original code in controller as below

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var userModelSerice =new UserModelService();
    var user = userModelService.load(1);
    return View(user);
}
```

All the remaining code reference above is as below

```
public class AddressRepository
{
    public Address LoadForUserId(int id)
    {
        // Load the address for given user id
    }
}

public class UserRepository
{
    public User Load(int id)
    {
        // Load and return user
    }
}

public class User
{
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
}
```

Now in your controller action, instead of creating a new instance of `UserModelService`, you can have it injected through constructor. Similar principle can be applied to inject the repositories into `UserModelService` but that would be another big discussion so I would cut myself short here.